# MVC 5 - HTML Content from Database - Paths Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

None of the "questions that may already have your answer" addresses my issue so here we go:

I have stored some links into database e.g.

```
<p>You can download it <a href="~/Documents/Stuff/1.pdf">here</a>.</p>
```

However the link no matter tilde or dots resolves to e.g.

```
http://localhost:6300/Home/Documents/Stuff/1.pdf
```

I am using Html.Raw when reading the content but not quite sure what to do with the links in order to make them working properly.

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem really? Are you not looking at the site from a localhost  or is "Home" the issue?

Comment: The Home ... i am expecting to get http://localhost:6300/Documents/Stuff/1.pdf Thx

Comment: Try stripping the tilde from link

Comment: I tried already. I added two dots which makes it go one level back but it's not what i want actually. I want to say ROOT + HREF e.g. there could be the culture too so it will not work again etc. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
<p>You can download it <a href="/Documents/Stuff/1.pdf">here</a>.</p>
```

I.e. No tilde and just a slash as this will resolve to the root of your website.